# Quotient set cardinal in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

In $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ define the equivalence relation xRy if $x^2 = y^2$

Then what is the cardinal of the quotient set?

Comment: I only know that $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ has 12 elements but I don't know how affect the relation.

Comment: Do you know what an equivalence class is?

Comment: Yes, an equivalence class is the class of an element of the set when there is an equivalence relation in the set.

Comment: The quotient set is (apart from some semantic details) the same as the set of equivalence classes. So it's just a matter of figuring out how many of those there are.

Comment: So, I think that the equivalence class in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ are 0,1,2,3,5,7,11? Then the answer would be 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are only 12 elements, you can simply check this element by element. Clearly $\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3}$ form distinct equivalence classes since their squares are all different. Since $\bar{4}^2=\bar{2}^2, \bar{5}^2 = \bar{1}^2, \bar{6}^2=\bar{0}^2, \bar{7}^2=\bar{1}^2,\bar{8}^2=\bar{2}^2,\bar{9}^2=\bar{3}^2,\bar{10}^2=\bar{2}^2,\bar{11}^2=\bar{1}^2$, we know that this is a complete list. Therefore there are only 4 equivalence classes.

Comment: Then you say that the cardinal of the quotient set is 5?

Comment: I actually made a mistake - the answer should be 4 since there are 4 equivalence classes, not 5.